# Youtube dl Unable to extract video data 't' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: error-handling, youtube

Hello so I would like to begin with that I am not extremely tech savvy. I am trying to download a video so that I can reformat it. I keep on receiving and error that says "unable to extract video data 't' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I tried to update youtube-dl, but it said it couldn't find an new version. I'm not sure if the issue I am having is that I can't update youtube-dl or if there is an issue with me downloading the video itself.

Here is the script line that I used to download the video.

C:\Users\name> YouTube-dl.exe -f bestvideo+bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llRfY17n-Lo&t=321s
[youtube] llRfY17n-Lo: Downloading webpage
ERROR: llRfY17n-Lo: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data
't' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Here is the scripts I used to try and update Youtube dl.

C:\Users\name>youtube-dl.exe -U
ERROR: can't find the current version. Please try again later.

C:\Users\name>youtube-dl -U
ERROR: can't find the current version. Please try again later.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems with the following errors:

```
'v' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

and

```
'feature' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I fixed the error and was able to download the file by entering the following command in command line and pressing enter:

```
youtube-dl **video identifier**
```

where video identifier is the series of digits that comes after **"v="**.
For example, if your video URL is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMH0bHeiRNg --> the identifier is dMH0bHeiRNg and the whole command is:

```
youtube-dl dMH0bHeiRNg
```

Actually I have found another solution to this:

1. in Windows, open the folder that you want to download the video in, say it is C:\Users\username
2. Then press CTRL+L and write cmd and press enter. Now the command line opens at the desired folder. (Make sure the folder is not under Windows or system32.)
3. Write **youtube-dl youtube.com/your_url** and press enter and it should download the video just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the Youtube URL includes a timestamp. This is usually the case for a video that you are partway through.

To fix the issue, delete the `t` and everything after it (so https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKJoNQx7c-I&t=3s becomes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKJoNQx7c-I&).